# Application.ExecutablePath different in Unit Test than in Debug C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, config, app-config

When debugging the line

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Aplication.Executable will return my programs .EXE file path in the Bin\Debug.

however during Unit testing, it will return Visual Studios .EXE file path rather than my programs. Is there any way around this? I've searched and I've noticed people mentioned to try using something like

```
var execPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

and then passing that like

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(execPath);
```

however, execPath seems to return just the folder, and not the programs EXE itself.

thanks

Comment: what if you do the following without using the `Configuration` and just get the full path with the .Exe filename as well 
`var execFilenae = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;`

Comment: That appears to return the DLL not the EXE

Comment: If you are talking about "Unit Tests" any reason your code cannot isolate dependencies so you can mock/stub what is returning from the Config Manager? Unit Test should not rely on the paths in file system.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment:

> If you are talking about "Unit Tests" any reason your code cannot
>   isolate dependencies so you can mock/stub what is returning from the
>   Config Manager? Unit Test should not rely on the paths in file system.

Just want to add bit more to this. I understand you have issues with paths when running in real live code vs Unit tests. If you approach the situation differently and think what you really trying Unit Test, then you probably will not encounter the issue you having right now.

There are plenty of examples in the Web on how to stub/mock configuration and file paths for Unit Testing purposes. But below is a link might help you in the right direction.

http://chrisondotnet.com/2011/05/configurationmanager-wrapper-for-unit-testing/